# orthogonal projection of the null vector

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H$ a Hilbert space, $V$ a subspace of $H$, and $P:H\to V$ a projector operator ($P^2=P$ and for any $v\in V$, $(I-P)(v)\in V^\perp$). Then $P(0_H)=0_H$. This is because $0_H=0_V\subset V$ and any projection of a vector of $V$, projects itself.

it's correct that I expressed above?

Comment: Yes you are right. Also note that for any linear operator $T$, $T(0)=0$, and $0_H=0_V$